# Key value coding of Objective-C struct properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, key-value-coding

According to Apple's documentation [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html) you can call valueForKey: and setValue:forKey: on struct properties and they should be automatically wrapped in NSValue objects.  I'm finding that when I make this call on an NSDecimal I get the following error:

`-[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]: struct with unknown contents found while getting argument at index -1`

Can anyone shed light on how this is supposed to be done?  Or is KVO broken for this case...

Comment: Show the actual code for when you make the call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Key-Value Coding does not work with structs containing *bit fields*.
So for this test class

```
typedef struct { int a; int b; } mystruct1;
typedef struct { int a:4; int b:4; } mystruct2;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) mystruct1 s1;
@property (nonatomic) mystruct2 s2;  // struct with bit fields
@end
```

the following works, and returns a `NSValue` object:

```
MyClass *o = [[MyClass alloc] init];
mystruct1 s1 = { 4, 5 };
o.s1 = s1;
NSValue *v1 = [o valueForKey:@"s1"];
```

but the same code with the struct containing bit fields crashes with exactly the same
message as in your question:

```
mystruct2 s2 = { 4, 5 };
o.s2 = s2;
NSValue *v2 = [o valueForKey:@"s2"]; // --> NSInvalidArgumentException
```

Since `NSDecimal` contains bit fields, this explains the problem.