# NSTableView sorting decimal column causes exception

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nssortdescriptor

I have a NSTableView that I am using to experiment with sorting columns. The string, integer and date columns seem to work fine but the decimal column is causing a crash which I'm scratching my head over.

Here's the data structure:

```
class LearningStruct : NSObject, Decodable {
    @objc var ID : Int
    @objc var Text : String
    @objc var Description : String
    @objc var CreationDate : Date
    @objc var UpdateDateTime : Date?
    @objc var ValueX: Decimal
    @objc var IsTrue : Bool
}
```

(Note the use of @objc and NSObject, apparently Swift can't natively handle key value coding required for sorting)

I create some test JSON data:

```
let learningJSON = "{\"Items\": [{\"ID\": 1, \"Text\": \"Item 1 text\", \"Description\": \"This is item 1 description\", \"CreationDate\": \"02/17/2019\", \"ValueX\": 123.45, \"UpdateDate\": \"02/17/2019\", \"IsTrue\": true}, {\"ID\": 2, \"Text\": \"Item 2 text\", \"Description\": \"This is item 2 description\", \"CreationDate\": \"02/14/2019\", \"ValueX\": 789.01, \"UpdateDate\": \"02/14/2019\", \"IsTrue\": false}]}"
internal var learningItems = [LearningStruct]()
```

Then I use the decoder to populate the array:

```
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
            dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy" // "MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss"
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateformatter)
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let learningData = try decoder.decode(LearningItems.self, from: learningJSON.data(using: .utf8)!) as LearningItems
            learningItems = learningData.Items
```

The NSTableColumns have their Identifier set to the property name in the storyboard for easy mapping.

```
           for prop in properties {
                let colindex = learningTableView.column(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier.init(prop)) // Get the column index number for that property key
                if (colindex >= 0) { // If the column exists
                    let descriptorID = NSSortDescriptor(key: prop, ascending: true)
                    learningTableView.tableColumns[colindex].sortDescriptorPrototype = descriptorID
                }
            }
```

Here's the sorting logic:

```
/// Sorting logic
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, sortDescriptorsDidChange oldDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) {

        print("--- Sorting logic begin ---")

        // Debug print the sorters
        for col in learningTableView.tableColumns {

            if col.sortDescriptorPrototype != nil {
                let sorter = col.sortDescriptorPrototype!.key!
                let direction = col.sortDescriptorPrototype!.ascending
                print("Column \(col.identifier.rawValue): sort descriptor: \(sorter), is ascending: \(direction)")
            } else {
                print("Column \(col.identifier.rawValue): no sort descriptor")
            }
        }

        print("+++ Sort descriptors list")
        let learningItemsMutable = NSMutableArray(array: learningItems)
        let sorters = tableView.sortDescriptors
        for sortdesc in sorters {
            print("Sort descriptor: \(sortdesc.key!)")
        }
        print("Sorting...")
        learningItemsMutable.sort(using: sorters)
        learningItems = learningItemsMutable as! [LearningStruct]
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("--- Sorting logic end ---")
    }
```

When I run the code, it sorts everything perfectly when I click on a column until I get to the "ValueX" column. The example below is me clicking on each column in order, ending with "Value X". When I click that, I get an exception that doesn't really help me... can anyone assist?

```
--- Sorting logic begin ---
Column ID: sort descriptor: ID, is ascending: true
Column Text: sort descriptor: Text, is ascending: true
Column Description: sort descriptor: Description, is ascending: true
Column CreationDate: sort descriptor: CreationDate, is ascending: true
Column ValueX: sort descriptor: ValueX, is ascending: true
Column IsTrue: sort descriptor: IsTrue, is ascending: true
+++ Sort descriptors list
Sort descriptor: ValueX
Sort descriptor: CreationDate
Sort descriptor: Description
Sort descriptor: Text
Sort descriptor: ID
Sorting...
2019-02-22 12:29:27.093825+0000 NSTableView Learning[8571:1649436] [General] -[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:]: struct with unknown contents found while getting argument at index -1
2019-02-22 12:29:27.095961+0000 NSTableView Learning[8571:1649436] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4aecaded __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff76f96720 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4ae22af3 -[NSInvocation getArgument:atIndex:] + 473
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff4d251a85 _NSGetValueWithMethod + 174
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff4d184494 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 284
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff4d193d68 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 389
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff4d1be3c9 -[NSMutableArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortUsingDescriptors:] + 497
    7   NSTableView Learning                0x000000010000d3c9 $S20NSTableView_Learning0cB10ControllerC05tableB0_24sortDescriptorsDidChangeySo0aB0C_SaySo16NSSortDescriptorCGtF + 5289
    8   NSTableView Learning                0x000000010000dacf $S20NSTableView_Learning0cB10ControllerC05tableB0_24sortDescriptorsDidChangeySo0aB0C_SaySo16NSSortDescriptorCGtFTo + 111
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff48b9e388 -[NSTableView _sendDataSourceSortDescriptorsDidChange:] + 82
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff4862275a -[NSTableView setSortDescriptors:] + 327
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff48b9e5ca -[NSTableView _changeSortDescriptorsForClickOnColumn:] + 542
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff48b81d73 -[NSTableHeaderView _trackAndModifySelectionWithEvent:onColumn:stopOnReorderGesture:] + 1000
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff48b84eeb -[NSTableHeaderView mouseDown:] + 596
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff4859f1eb -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5668
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff484d3223 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2319
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff484d26c9 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 481
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff4836f954 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 336
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff4835d19d -[NSApplication run] + 755
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff4834c8a3 NSApplicationMain + 780
    20  NSTableView Learning                0x000000010001085d main + 13
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff78064ed9 start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Comment: One quick comment I forgot to mention: the boolean column also sorts properly.

Comment: struct with unknown contents found while getting argument at index -1. This somehow tells me you are dealing with -1 as index. Set exception breakpoint and see why it is happening

Comment: I added some debug print statements to help with this post. The actual exception occurs right after the "sorting..." print statement: "learningItemsMutable.sort(using: sorters)" which unfortunately does not expose where the index is.

Comment: lldb -n "getArgument:atIndex:" + add condition $rcx==-1, print statements are waste of time, exception breakpoint is not print statement (maybe google how to add it)

Comment: I only provided the print statements to help show where the code was crashing for the benefit of clarity in this post. As you suggested, I added an exception breakpoint which produced a list of function calls closely aligned to what I provided above. It's clear that something is wrong with the key-value sorting for ValueX. Would you be able to explain a bit more about how to execute this command, "lldb -n "getArgument:atIndex:" + add condition $rcx==-1"?

Comment: Answered you in the other comment down. KVC doesn't support all C structs. No need to debug more. For lldb and manual adding breakpoints there is great tutorial (section breakpoints) https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/ Once you read this you will know hot to debug on advanced level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The used type `Decimal`, in Objective-C `NSDecimal` is not in the list of supported key-value-coding types. [KVC documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/DataTypes.html)

```
typedef struct {
    signed   int _exponent:8;
    unsigned int _length:4;     // length == 0 && isNegative -> NaN
    unsigned int _isNegative:1;
    unsigned int _isCompact:1;
    unsigned int _reserved:18;
    unsigned short _mantissa[NSDecimalMaxSize];
} NSDecimal;
```

The `NSDecimal` uses bit fields which are the key issue.

Every attempt to make it work (this should be possible) will be not Codable out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Might be some problem with how `Decimal` is bridged with [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber)

Try using `NSDecimalNumber` in your `LearningStruct` class to see it the crash is still there.

Alternatively create a new read only property and use it for sorting instead:

```
class LearningStruct: NSObject, Decodable {
    @objc var ID: Int
    @objc var Text: String
    @objc var Description: String
    @objc var CreationDate: Date
    @objc var UpdateDateTime: Date?
    @objc var ValueX: Decimal
    @objc var IsTrue: Bool

    @objc var ValueXNumber: NSDecimalNumber {
        return ValueX as NSDecimalNumber
    }
}
```

Relevant notes: instance variables are usually named with a lowercase first letter in Swift. And `@objc` is required because `NSSortDescriptor` is an Objective-C class and it would not see the properties of your Swift class otherwise.

Comment: I tried both, and unfortunately neither option worked. Using the property as a NSDecimalNumber caused the class to no longer be decodable. And using the getter method didn't work because I'm using Mirror() to get the property names and it doesn't show up.

Comment: I will however rename the instance variables... although I'm actually using them to match up against the JSON and I'm un-camel-casing them to create column headers so this might be tricky.

Comment: KVC (getValue:forKey) with structs (NSDecimal in your case) only works for certain struct types https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/DataTypes.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958095/key-value-coding-of-objective-c-struct-properties

Comment: THANK YOU! That is clearly the answer - the Decimal type is not in the list of supported KVC scalar types. Pending further tests, the solution that seems to work for me is to use Double instead of Decimal in the NSObject class. @Marek H, can you please hit the "answer" button with your comment and I'll mark this as the solution.